# Finding Max value in a column of csv file PYTHON

Tags: python, csv

I'm fairly new to coding, and I'm stuck on a current project. I have a .csv file, and rather than use a spreadsheet, I'm trying to write a python program to find the maximum value of a specific column. So far I have the following:

```
import csv

with open('american_colleges__universities_1993.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    answer = 0
    for column in reader :
        answer = 0
        for i in column[14]:
            if i>answer:
                answer = i
print answer
```

I keep getting something like:

```
9
```

The problem is that this is only returning the largest integer (which happens to be 9), when it should be returning something like 15,000. I suspect the program is only looking at each digit as its own value... How can I get it to look at the entire number in each entry?

Sorry for the newb question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are comparing each character in `column[14]` and setting the lexically maximum character to `answer`. Assuming you want to arithmetically compare the whole of `column[14]` you will need to `replace` the comma with `''` and convert to `int`, e.g.:

```
with open('american_colleges__universities_1993.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)     # Skip header row
    answer = max(int(column[14].replace(',', '')) for column in reader)
print answer
```

If you need the whole row that has the maximum `column[14]` you could alternatively use the `key` argument to `max`:

```
    answer = max(reader, key=lambda column: int(column[14].replace(',','')))
print answer
```

Comment: So, the first row in the column is text. How can I skip it to look at the actual number? I've tried    next(f)

Comment: You can `next(reader)` before the `max` call to skip the header line. Alternatively you can look into `DictReader` and then use `column['ColumnName']`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
with open('american_colleges__universities_1993.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    maxnum = max(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[14]))
print(maxnum)
```

This should do the work for you.